# Perl - match begin / end string in a file

Tags: perl, match

How do I write a PERL for the below:

- I would like to read in a file.
- Then match between GAME and END from the file read in. I want the line that has "GOOD CATCH 1 5 15 5 15" to become "GOOD CATCH 1 10 30 10 30". The final number is multiply by 2 or 3 or 4...etc.
- Print out the same file but with the changed above.

```
Input file
***********
GAME
     BALL X1 ;
     GOOD CATCH 1 5 15 5 15 ;
END
```

```
Output file
***********
GAME
     BALL X1 ;
     GOOD CATCH 1 10 30 10 30 ;
END
```

```
# I am not sure how to match $GOOD CATCH line and multiply the last 4 digit. Is there such a thing as LINDEX or SCAN in perl?

open (infile, "<", "inputfile.txt") or die "could not open:$!";
open (outfile, ">", "outputfile.txt") or die "could not open:$!";


while (<infile>)
     if (/GAME/) {
         if (/BALL X1/) {
            $GOOD CATCH = 
         }
      }
     elseif (/END) {
     print ;
     }

close (inffie);
close (outfile);
```

Comment: Tip: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look on a parser like [`Regexp::Grammars`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars). Anyway, here is a simpler approach using regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = "file.txt";
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
$str =~ s/^(GAME.*?^END)/multiply($1)/msge;
print $str;


sub multiply {
    my ( $str ) = @_;

    $str =~ s/(GOOD CATCH.*?;)/_multiply($1)/ge;
    return $str;
}


sub _multiply {
    my ( $str ) = @_;

    $str =~ s/(\d+)/_mul_number($1)/ge;
    return $str;
}

sub _mul_number {
    my ($num) = @_;

    return $num * 2;
}
```

**Output**:

```
GAME
     BALL X1 ;
     GOOD CATCH 2 10 30 10 30 ;
END
```

Comment: Thank you. So, if you want to print out to a file. Do you just open an output file and print $outfilename instead of $str? I would like to print out the whole file with the "Updated multiplied line".

Comment: Yes you can do that. Or simply redirect the output in the shell: `perl prog.pl > output.txt`

Comment: Maybe you could send me the code you tried? (My email is in my profile). Then I will have a look at it.

Comment: Hi, I will also need to match "BALL X1". How do I put into the code? So, the start and end is (GAME AND END), then it will match (BALL X1) and (GOOD CATCH)?

Comment: Yes you can do that! I did not receive your email yet

Comment: I did not get any email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217980/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-jay).